# tensorflow: sliding neighborhood mask

Tags: tensorflow, mask

How to make a sliding neighborhood mask, For example, for a 5-neighbor mask, suppose the mask dimension is [6, 6], then the mask should look like:

```
[[1 1 1 0 0 0]  #mask at pos 1
 [1 1 1 1 0 0]  #mask at pos 2
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]  #mask at pos 3
 [0 1 1 1 1 1]] #mask at pos 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `linalg.band_part()`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
input = tf.ones((6, 6), tf.int32)
output = tf.linalg.band_part(input, 2, 2)
```